# Javascript syntax errors when using ZAP as proxy in IIS Web Application

Tags: javascript, iis, owasp, zap

I have a working ASP.NET application I would like to test with ZAP.  I have created a certificate from ZAP and imported the certificate into the local browser that I am using for testing.  With the ZAP proxy running, I am able to log into my application and see the corresponding information populate in ZAP.

When I attempt to navigate anywhere in my application, my application is catching the following error:

```
Window: https://mymachine.mycompany.com/myapplication/mypage.mvc/Index
 Message:   {"browserEvent":"Syntax error","button":-1,"ctrlKey":false,"xy":[0,0]}

=======================
    Stack
=======================


StackItem [1]
----------------------------------------
 Function:
 function h(e){
            // prevent errors while unload occurring
            if(!Ext){// !window[xname]){  ==> can't we do this?
                return;
            }
            e = Ext.EventObject.setEvent(e);
            var t;
            if (o.delegate) {
                if(!(t = e.getTarget(o.delegate, el))){
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                t = e.target;
            }
            if (o.stopEvent) {
                e.stopEvent();
            }
            if (o.preventDefault) {
               e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (o.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
            if (o.normalized) {
                e = e.browserEvent;
            }

            fn.call(scope || el, e, t, o);
        }

Arguments:
    1)  (string)    "Syntax error"
    2)  (string)    "https://mymachine.mycompany.com/zapCallBackUrl/5196725491219408217/inject.js"
    3)  (number)    7
    4)  (null)
```

This application implements the EXTJS presentation Framework as well.  The syntax error appears to be coming from the javascript that ZAP injects, but I have submitted it to several javascript validators that report it is valid.

I've reviewed the IIS logs and found no errors there.

Why is there a syntax error in the javascript that ZAP is injecting and how can I correct/prevent it?

Comment: You haven't asked a question... Disable HUD and proceed as usual...

Comment: HUD is not enabled.  Why is there a syntax error in the javascript that ZAP is injecting and how can I correct/prevent it?

Comment: HUD must have been enabled or you wouldn't be seeing it's inject.js.